# jQuery onclick the <li> will fade out

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

I have this question: is my code correct?
What I am trying to do here is when I click the button 'Select' and insert the value of the button it will fadeout meaning it was added to my database.

The jQuery code here I added the $('li#static').fadeout();

Here's the code:

```
// AJAX/JQUERY FORM
$(function() {
    $(".videoThumbS").click(function() {

        $("li#static").fadeout();

        var dataString = $(this).siblings('input[name="v_w_id"]').val();
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',                                  
            url: 'api.php',
            data: { v_w_id: dataString },
            dataType: 'html',               
            success: function(data) {
                var viewrecord = dataString;
                $('.selected_thumbs').append("<img class='appendPL' src=http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + viewrecord +"/default.jpg />");
            } 
        });    
    });
});
```

My button is:

```
<input id="v_w_id_value" type="hidden" name="v_w_id" value="' . $yValue['videoid'] . '" />
<input class="videoThumbS" type="button" name="selectSel" value="Select" id="selectbut" />
```

Is my code correct?

Comment: did it work? ;-) (PS, you are still making the mistake of repeating your `id` and `name` attributes incorrectly, judging from this sample code)

Answer (score 1):

Put the `$("li#static").fadeout();` inside your success function so that the fadeout will only occur after it has inserted into the db.

Comment: hi ubercooluk, if i do that all the list of my playlist wast gone, if i use the .hide() it also hide all the playlist, please see this sample link of my website. http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/index.php

Comment: Update your question with the corresponding HTML (The list)

Comment: I cant access your localhost..post the HTML in your question

Comment: This user has asked a few questions tonight, and has been told about incorrect use of attributes; however, they continue to not use `id` and `name` properly. I would hesitate to troubleshoot TOOooo much until the user fixes these issues in the underlying markup.

Comment: that is so mean for newbie like me. thanks anyway will ask other how i can solve this problem. please note that not everyperson here is like you. Greg Pettit

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives:

1. use `complete: function() {$("li#static").fadeout();}` on your AJAX request
2. use `$(element).ajaxStop(function() {$("li#static").fadeout();});`